# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyedflib' even though pyedflib has been installed

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyedflib' even though pyedflib has been installed (when checked, it says requirement satisfied).

I have uninstalled it and reinstalled to make sure it installed correctly. Numpy requirement is satisfied.  Has anyone else come across this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a virtual environment and install `pyedflib`

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pyEDFlib
```

now you can run `python3` in the same environment and get the import working

```
python3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyedflib
```

Comment: Thank you, Shabari. I already work in venv and everything is installed in venv. I have done the second part of your suggestion and got the following:

Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyedflib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyedflib'

It doesn't seem to pick up that pyedflib was installed via pip. I did that again, and it said requirement satisfied.

Comment: You sure your `venv` was active when you ran `pip install pyEDFlib` ? Did you run `source venv/bin/activate` ??